# "soup.prettify()" gives just URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python3, BeautifulSoup4

When I run code below, it gives just url "www.google.com" not XML.
I couldn't find it What is wrong.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib


html = "www.google.com"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


print (soup.prettify())
```

Comment: `"www.google.com"` is not HTML. Download the HTML with `urllib2` or `requests`.

Comment: please, read again tutorial/documentation you followed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use urllib2 or a similar library to fetch the HTML

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("www.google.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print (soup.prettify())
```

EDIT: Just as a side note to clarify why I suggested urllib2. If you read the urllib documentation, you'll find "The urlopen() function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of urllib2.urlopen()." Given that you have tagged Python3, urllib2 would probably be your best option.